# how to show friendly message while task completes

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I don't know if I've even asked the question properly, but I have a codeigniter application that some heaving lifting in the back end.  While the app is busy executing commands(ajax commands), I'd like to show some sort of a status / message box / div.  When the task is done, I'd like to clear the div / box. 
What would I need to google to find a solution like this?

Thanks.

**Edit:** 
This is what my jquery / ajax call looks like right now...

```
  $('#availVLANS').click(function()  {
  $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
  $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo site_url('controller/methodABC/');?>",
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(returnDataFromController) {
    var htmlstring;
    var submitFormHTML;
    htmlstring = "<br><br><B>To reassign the port to a new vlan, click on a VlanId below and then click on the OK button</B><br><table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
    htmlstring = htmlstring + "<th>VlanId</th><th>Name</th>";
    for(i = 0; i < returnDataFromController.length; i++) {
        //alert(returnDataFromController[i].VlanId);
        htmlstring = htmlstring +  "<tr><td><a href=>"+returnDataFromController[i].VlanId+"</a></td><td>"+ returnDataFromController[i].Name+"</td></tr>";   

    }
    submitFormHTML = "<form method='post' accept-charset='utf-8' action='" + BASEPATH + "index.php/switches/changeportvlan/"+ $('#ip').val() +"/" + $('#hardwaremodel').val() +"/" + $('#port').val() + "'><input type='text' name='newVlanID' id='newVlanID' style='width:5em;height:1.5em'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type='submit' class='btn' name='saveVlan' id='saveVlan' style='width:10em;height:2em'>Reassign Vlan</button></form>";
    //alert(submitFormHTML);
    $('#clientajaxcontainer').html(htmlstring);
    $('#newvlanform').html(submitFormHTML);                     

  }
});
$(this).removeAttr("disabled");
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an animated GIF image in an absolutely positioned DIV overlayed on top of the whole page. Just make sure that you overlay an invisible DIV over top of the entire page to prevent clicks on interface elements behind the progress window. Something like this;

```
╔════════════════════╗
║  #progress-overlay ║
║ ╔════════════════╗ ║
║ ║ #progress-indicator
║ ╚════════════════╝ ║
╚════════════════════╝
```

The #progress-overlay is a background for the indicator and what you're going for is like a LightBox2 effect but using a progress indicator and small box in the middle of the screen.

You can get animated gif's from here; 
http://preloaders.net/

Make sure that your progress/something-is-happening div sits at the top level of the document structure, so somewhere at the top of the body, before any of your other container DIV's. This is done so that the #progress-overlay is rendered at the same level in the DOM as the top level element of your website. When you absolutely position the #progress-overlay, it will appear **overtop** of everything else on the page.

```
<html>
<head>
....
</head>
<body>
<div id="progress-overlay">
    <div id="progress-indicator">
        <img src="images/myprogress.gif" /> Please Wait...
    </div>
</div><!--progress-overlay-->
<div id="website-wrapper">
.... web site, layout, content, etc...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The #progress-overlay is hidden by default and then shown overtop when needed. Something like;

```
#progress-overlay{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #000;
opacity: 0.2;
}

#progress-indicator{
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
top: 40%;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
}
```

Using JQuery you could easily make this appear on demand using;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#progress-overlay').hide();
    });
function showProgressIndicator()
{
    $('#progress-overlay').show();
}
```

Comment: how would i change the css so that the div always appeared in the middle of the page? I'm using bootstrap and would like to make the divs dynamic..

Comment: The css in my demo here actually shows the use of margin: 0 auto; which sets the top/bottom margins to 0 and the left/right margins to auto. It should center the div at the top of the page, but you could additionally set a margin-top: 40%, which would put it "approximately" in the middle of the page vertically as well.

Comment: I suppose you can also use CSS z-ordering instead of the early placement of the overlay div in the HTML text, is that correct? (+1 BTW, and I enjoyed your Apache answer, too! :) )

Comment: Yes you can of course, and thank you I'm glad you enjoyed the answer on the Apache Directive stuff, I was pretty annoyed that day so i wrote a bit of a snarky novel on the whole thing :D

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of onreadystatechange event:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it through jquery, just show a div with a message and/or a spinner.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function() {
     $('#loader').show();
  },
  complete: function(){
     $('#loader').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, I propose the following solution:

### The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#the_button").click(function(){
        var url = "the_controller/the_method"
        var data = {the: "data"}
        //before the POST takes place, fade-in the message
        $("#the_message").fadeIn();
        $.post(url, data, function(r){
            if(r.success){
                //when the post is finished, and it was successful, fade-out the message.
                $("#the_message").fadeOut();
            }
            else console.log("something bad happened");
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

### The HTML:

```
<!-- HIDE IT BY DEFAULT -->
<div id='the_message' style='display:none;'>
    Please wait.
</div>
```

### The Controller:

```
class The_controller extends CI_Controller{
    function the_method(){
        $p = $this->input->post();
        the_task($p);
        if(the_task_success) return json_encode(array("success" => true));
        else return json_encode(array("success" => false));
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i'm just an ajax / jquery newbie.  So how would i modify your solution to fit my code?  i've edited my post to include my javascript as it is now.